# NSString substringWithRange crash

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

I have this code:

```
- (void)splitAndSendString:(NSString *)string
             withAlignment:(UITextAlignment)alignment
         verticalExpansion:(NSUInteger)verticalExpansion
       horizontalExpansion:(NSUInteger)horizontalExpansion
                     inRed:(BOOL)isRed
          leftBumperString:(NSString *)leftString
         rightBumperString:(NSString *)rightString
                lineLength:(NSUInteger)lineLength
{
    NSInteger charactersLeftAfterString = lineLength - [string length] -
            [leftString length] - [rightString length];

   // if either of the bumpers is nil, then replace it with @""
   //so that we don't get "null" printed
   if (leftString == nil)  { leftString = @"";     }
   if (rightString == nil) { rightString = @"";    }

   if (charactersLeftAfterString < 0) {
        NSInteger charactersAvailableForString =
           [string length] + charactersLeftAfterString;
        [self sendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", leftString, [string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, charactersAvailableForString)], rightString] withAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft verticalExpansion:verticalExpansion horizontalExpansion:horizontalExpansion inRed:isRed];
   }
   //(a lot of other code here that isn't relevant)
}
```

It's crashing on the sendString method, because of a bad NSRange. I don't understand how this is possible given charactersLeftAfterString is necessarily less than 0 given the condition of the if statement, so charactersAvailableForString is always less than the string length, so how can the range be longer than the string length?

Comment: I would say some relevant code is left out, for example the caller. If `lineLength` is not correct then none of the other calculations will be correct.

Comment: You're right, but how it comes up with that number is relatively esoteric and complicated, basically it's always 33 or over. Never 0.

Comment: you should try to log all these numeric values. You will soon find why the range gets invalid

Comment: @refulgentis: Log and store all ranges in temporary variables. Then you can single step each line in the debugger, and I bet you will find your small logical error quite fast. Inspecting the code execute, beats guessing every time.

Comment: @PeyloW - thanks but I didn't write that code

Comment: @Vince - But refulgent is did :). Updated for proper addressing, and the intended up vote on your comment.

Comment: Unforuntaely, I don't have access to the variable values that are causing this crash – I'm just seeing the crash in a crash report.

Answer (score 2):

Have you used the debugger and checked the value of `charactersAvailableForString`?

... or printed it?

... or looked at the value when it crashes?

Comment: +1 This is straight forward and should point directly to the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't, it's from a crash report. I'm thinking about writing some sort of harness that just throws a bunch of strings at it.

Comment: Put in some assertions such that when the bad state occurs, you could abort whatever is going on.  And, if at all possible, present the user with a "Hey, mind if I submit something back to me to make the app better?" dialog.

Answer (score 2):

If your string  is empty, i.e [string length] = 0

[string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, charactersAvailableForString)]

will always give a NSRange exception every time, no matter what as

charactersAvailableForString < 0

Also similar problems can arise if [string length] = 5 and charactersLeftAfterString = -12.
charactersAvailableForString = 5-12 = -7
[string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, charactersAvailableForString)] will give NsRange Exception.